# I'm trying to get data from my database, but cursoroutofbound exception

Tags: android, sqlite

****This is my database code, when i use getVenue(), i get exception..**
Any can help me to solve this problem??? please

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NAME + " TEXT," + BOOKMARK
            + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}


public void addVenue(Venue v) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, v.getId());
    values.put(NAME, v.getComment());
    values.put(BOOKMARK, v.getBookmark());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();


}

public Venue getVenue(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] { ID, NAME, BOOKMARK }, ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Venue v = new Venue(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table declaration, ID is specified as a integer, but then you try to query it as a string ( String.valueOf(id).  Strings in SQLite need to be surrounded by " ' " characters, such as '9'.   As a test, try setting your search query to "ID=1", and null the whereargs, as such:

```
public Venue getVenue(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
        new String[] { ID, NAME, BOOKMARK }, ID + "=1",
        null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();
Venue v = new Venue(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
return v;
}
```

Then use the following to see if it worked:

```
Log.d("cusor results for row 1: ", "Cursor Row: "+String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0) + ", Name: " + cursor.getString(1) + ", Bookmark: " + cursor.getString(2))
```

Also, your cursor.getString(0) is incorrect, since your first column is your ID column, which is an Integer, so you would use "cursor.getInt(0)"